# Why is it not possible to implement fixed-point combinator like in the definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to implement the Y-combinator [like in the definition by Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator).

This code does not work. It causes infinite recursion.

```
F = (lambda f: (lambda x: (1 if x == 0 else (x * (f(x-1))))))    
Y = (
    lambda f: 
    (lambda x: f(x(x)))
    (lambda x: f(x(x)))
)
Y(F)(3)
```

However, this one does work:

```
Y = (
    lambda f: 
    (lambda x: f(
        lambda v: x(x)(v)
    ))
    (lambda x: f(
        lambda v: x(x)(v)
    ))
)
Y(F)(3)
```

Why is the first one not working, but the second one is?

Comment: Cited from the Wikipedia article: *"Applied to a function with one variable the Y combinator usually does not terminate."* And [later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Usage_in_programming): *"Fixed point combinators can be used to implement recursive definition of functions. However, they are rarely used in practical programming. Strongly normalizing type systems such as the simply typed lambda calculus disallow non-termination and hence fixed-point combinators often cannot be assigned a type or require complex type system features."*. So this seems to be expected.

Comment: YF should be the faculty, and hence terminate.

Comment: `Y(F)` yields infinite recursion, because Python evaluates the beta-reduction mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed-point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) eagerly: `YF = F(YF) = F(F(YF)) = ...` While this is formal notation in the article, Python does exactly this, it evaluates the self-recursive argument ad infinitum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python evaluates all function arguments eagerly and this is what causes infinite recursion for the Y-combinator. As stated in the [linked Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Strict_fixed-point_combinator):

> In a strict programming language the Y combinator will expand until stack overflow, or never halt in case of tail call optimization.

In order to prevent that "eagerness", one can replace the direct function call `x(x)` with another lambda function. Being hidden inside that lambda function prevents it from evaluating straightaway. That's what you've done in your second version: `lambda v: x(x)(v)`. This form is then known as the Z-combinator (see the Wikipedia article above).

Answer (score -2):

The first string prints out the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized
```

It causes an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But why?

Comment: BTW, where are you getting the rest of that error message from? I just get the first line (ignoring the stack trace ofc).